# Wrong color when convert UIColor to CGColor

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicolor, cgcolor

I don't get the correct color when i convert a UIColor to a CGColor.

This color :

```
 let color = UIColor(red: 198, green: 35.0, blue: 80.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

[image]

When i apply it on a CAlayer

```
layer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
layer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
```

will appear `white` on my phone !

[image]

As you can see the circle is white...

Comment: 198/255.0 and so on for each components. The target value is between 0 and 1, not 0 and 255. It's because `color` is wrong at the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Colors** in **UIKit** are specified using value is **between 0 and 1** in float not int from 0 to 255, so you need to divide all your RGB values by 255.0.

```
let color = UIColor(red: 198.0/255.0, green: 35.0/255.0, blue: 80.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```